# How to change the scale of the plot in R

Tags: r, image-processing, scale, raster

I have been trying to perform some of the raster related operations using R and whenever I am loading raster files in R in the plot window it is being displayed at a different scale which is hard to notice. I'm a little confused about how to bring it back to a standard size. As I'm new to the R language I'm not able to figure it out. Little help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. To help the community help you please include a minimal reproducible example which would include data, code and expected outcome  see [ask] and [reprex] for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the default values set in par() function. By changing the "mar" parameter in the function I was able to resize it to my own convenience.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyWAv.png)